# module not saved in the database

Tags: magento2

I created a ui component, but I have no idea how to save it in the database. I know I have to pass it to the controller for it to pass to the model but I don't know how my controller should be, here's my code:

form ui component:

```
 <dataSource name="novo_desconto_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Desconto\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">novo_desconto_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="employee_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="employee_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Nome</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_salary">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Valor</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_salary</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Desconto</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Desconto\Model;
 
use Vendor\Desconto\Model\ResourceModel\Employee\CollectionFactory;
 
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $employeeCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $employeeCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $employeeCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

My saveButton.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Desconto\Block\Adminhtml\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 * @package Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit
 */
class SaveButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry);
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();
        $canModify = !$customerId || !$this->customerAccountManagement->isReadonly($this->getCustomerId());
        $data = [];
        if ($canModify) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Salvar'),
                'class' => 'save primary',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                    'form-role' => 'save',
                ],
                'sort_order' => 90,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save', []);
    }
}




   <?php
namespace vendor\Desconto\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Employee extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\test\Model\ResourceModel\Employee');
    }
}
```

Model.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Desconto\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Employee extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('banktest', 'id_desconto');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple fieldsets happened to me that i had to set them "manually" like:

```
$rawData->setEmployeeName($data['employee_details']['employee_name']);
```

or if you have a plain form without tabs this should do the trick:

```
$rawData->setData($data);
```

You create a save action controller where you call your modelFactory witch create's or uses the current 'entity_id' to overwrite or create a new row.

Your controller should look like this,

```
<?php
    
    
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Employee;
    
    
    class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        var $employeeFactory;
    
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Vendor\Module\Model\EmployeeFactory $employeeFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->employeeFactory = $employeeFactory;
        }
    
    
        public function execute()
        {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            if (!$data) {
    
                $this->_redirect('vendor_module/employee/edit'); // your edit url
                return;
            }
    
            try {
                $rawData = $this->employeeFactory->create();
                $rawData->setData($data);
                if (isset($data['entity_id'])) {
                    $rawData->setEntityId($data['entity_id']);
                }
                $rawData->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
            }
            $this->_redirect('vendor_module/employee/index');
    
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

In Your ui component you have to declare the button:

```
<settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Employee\Edit\SaveButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add controller file for save data in database

create save.php on below path

> Vendor\Desconto\Controller\Adminhtml\Employee\save.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Desconto\Controller\Adminhtml\Employee;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    private $dataPersistor;

    private $employeeModel;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Vendor\Desconto\Model\Employee  $employeeModel
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->employeeModel = $employeeModel;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id_desconto');
        
            $model = $this->employeeModel->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This item no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        
            $model->setData($data);
        
            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
        
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id_desconto' => $model->getId()]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
            }
        
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id_desconto' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id_desconto')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }


}
```

hope this will help you :)

Comment: error 404, page not found, button is not leading to the controller. How can I solve this?

Comment: In saveButton.php you adeed get button data..here you not declared url so its not leading to controller.

Comment: and how I do it ? ;=;